# What is RFWS in eclipse rcp?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I am working in an RCP application in Eclipse indigo 3.7. I am given the requirement to fulfill RFWS considerations. I googled for that but didn't find anything.

Please suggest a link or code to help me understand RFWS.

Comment: I was also having this doubt.I searched alot and found this [link](http://www.parasoft.com/jsp/products/release.jsp?articleId=1033&type=2003)

Answer (score 1):

It's IBM's family of technical and user requirements for software built on some IBM product. RFWS is short for Ready for WebSphere.

For RCP developers is highly useful to get familiarized with RFRS (Ready for Rational Software) which is collection on well chosen considerations for every RCP application or plug-in.

Answer (score 1):

If I recall it correctly, RFWS stands for "Ready For WebSphere",later replaced by "Ready For Rational Software", and is a certification of the add-ons/plug-ins your developing.
Basically a set of requirements to ensure that what your building has a high quality.

Believe you must be an IBM Partner to get access to the program.

I searched for "Ready For Rational Software" and found this page (but then you must have a valid login to proceed, which I no longer have... ;-) :

https://www-304.ibm.com/partnerworld/wps/servlet/ContentHandler/isv_com_dvm_techval_rational